# Installing Hysterix turbine from WAR/JAR file

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netflix

I am a sydadmin and was evaluating Hysterix Turbine.

https://github.com/Netflix/Turbine/wiki/Getting-Started-(1.x)

It is available as a war/jar file.

Directory structure looks like this after downloading

```
$ ls turbine-4.0
conf  lib  LICENSE  NOTICE  README.txt  site  sql  turbine-4.0.jar
```

How to get this installed . If I download `tomcat` and put the above contents in deploy directory , will it work .

I am new to `JAVA` and `Tomcat`. So any help to get this installed will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Steps-

1. Download the war file from [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.netflix.turbine%20AND%20a:turbine-web&core=gav). If you are an absolute newbie, go with version 0.5. The version 0.0.1 has weird behaviour where it gives IOException while running multiple application instances on the same machine.
2. You should then deploy the war file to your tomcat by just placing it in the *webapps* folder in tomcat and starting the server. If your war name is *turbine.war*, you should be able to view your aggregated logs at [http://localhost:8080/turbine/turbine.stream?cluster={cluster-name}](http://localhost:8080/turbine/turbine.stream?cluster=%7Bcluster-name%7D)
3. Before deploying your *turbine.war*, make sure you configure the file path of archaius.properties in *catalina.sh* in *bin* folder in the tomcat. Something like-

   `CATALINA_OPTS="-Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=file:///home/mukulbansal/Downloads/oauth-stuff/turbine-archaius.properties"`

   The contents of *turbine-archaius.properties* can something be like-

   `turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig={cluster-name}`

   `turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.user-write=/hystrix.stream`

   `turbine.ConfigPropertyBasedDiscovery.{cluster-name}.instances={IP:port-of-application-producing-hystrix-event-stream}`

   `turbine.InstanceMonitor.eventStream.skipLineLogic.enabled=false`

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/Netflix/Turbine/wiki).